# Is my proof correct? I want to show if $V \subset H$ is dense, then $L^2(0,T;V) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$ is dense too.

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces

I want to show that if $V \subset H$ is a dense embedding then $L^2(0,T;V) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$ is dense too. Everything is a Hilbert space.

Let $h \in L^2(0,T;H)$. Then $h(t) \in H$ for each $t$. By density of $V$, there is a $v(t) \in V$ such that 
$$\lVert v(t) - h(t) \rVert_H \leq \epsilon.$$
So
$$\lVert v - h \rVert^2_{L^2(0,T;H)} = \int_0^T\lVert v(t) - h(t) \rVert_H^2\;dt \leq T\epsilon^2$$
which is what we wanted.

Is this a correct proof? I am not sure how to show that $v$ is integrable..

Comment: Why is $v(t)$ measurable? Try doing it in two steps: approximate $h$ by a simple function and then use density of $V$ to find a function with values in $V$ close to $h$.

Comment: @julien please see edit.

Comment: @Martin Can you give me another hint? I edited in your suggestions

Comment: By definition $a_i \in H$. Now take $b_i \in V$ close to $a_i$ and define $v = \sum_{i=1}^{M_n} b_i \chi_{A_i}$. With a little care you can ensure that $\lVert v - h\rVert \lt 2 \varepsilon$. (Meanwhile, +1 for your effort.)

Comment: @maximumtag I knew, but thanks. Your write-up would be clearer if you simply approximated the $a_i$'s. Oh, you've done it in between. Nicely done.

Comment: @Martin thank you, I think I got it now.

Comment: @julien Thanks, I believe I understand the proof now.

Comment: @maximumtag You could write it as an answer instead of putting it in the body of the question.

Comment: @julien Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Martin's suggestion:
By definition of Bochner space, there is a simple function 
$$h_n(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{M_n}a_{i}\chi_{A_i}(t) \in H$$
where $a_i \in H$ and $A_i$ is disjoint subset of $[0,T]$ such that
$$\lVert h_n - h \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H)} \leq \epsilon.$$
Since $a_i \in H$ and $V$ is dense in $H$, there exist $b_i \in V$ such that $\lVert b_i - a_i \rVert_H \leq \frac{\epsilon}{M_n\sqrt{T}}$. Then define $$v(t) = \sum_{i}b_i\chi_{A_i}(t)$$
which is measurable (in the sense that its norm in $L^2(0,T;H)$ exists).

$$\lVert v - h \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H)} = \lVert v(t) - h_n + h_n - h(t) \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H)} \leq \sum_i \lVert (a_i - b_i)\chi_{A_i}\rVert_{L^2(0,T;H)} + \epsilon \leq 2\epsilon$$

Comment: That's almost it. I would choose $b_i \in V$ such that $\lVert b_i - a_i\rVert_H \lt \varepsilon/(M_n \cdot T)$ or something like that, in order to ensure that $\lVert v - h\rVert_H \lt 2 \varepsilon$. (Otherwise the product $M_n \cdot \varepsilon$ need not go to zero when you let $\varepsilon \to 0$.)

Comment: For short: that's dense by transitivity of density. Simple $V$ valued functions are dense in simple $H$ valued functions. And the latter are dense in $L^2$.

Comment: @julien Nice point.